# jQuery Help needed in changing color in condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want a jQuery snippet for changing color of a button on condition-->
I am using `WooCommerce` with `WordPress`. What I want is : if there is Cart item is `0` then I want to show `red color` and if any item in cart then the button goes `green`

Comment: Can you show your near by jQuery code effort? So that we can help.

Comment: www.favdiva.com  look in the cart item count ,actully i need to add a  button below this is cart is empty then it will show red color and if any item is in cart then it will changes in to green...

Answer (score 1):

Put your item number in a div/span and give an id. For eaxample I took 'item_container' is the id of that div then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var item_nu = $('#item_container').html().parseInt();
    if(item_nu=='0')
     {
       //write your code here to make the button red
     }
    else{
       //write your code here to make the button green
     }
 })
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
   var item_nu = $('#item_container').html().parseInt();
    if(item_nu=='0')
     {
       $("#mybutton").addClass("myClass");
     }
    else{
       $("#mybutton").addClass("myotherClass");
     }
 })   and i will set css of those class is it right??

Comment: yes , in myClass calss wite css for red button and myotherClass class for green button.

Comment: http://onlinegiftstore.in/   please open this url and look the button i need to change color if cart is empty ..i am unable to do that ,thaxnx saifur for helping

Comment: var item_nu = $('.shop_countnumber span').html().parseInt();
        if(item_nu >0)
         {
           //write your code here to make the button green
         }
        else{
           //write your code here to make the button red
         }

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var item_nu = $('#color_change1').html().parseInt();
if(item_nu=='0')
{
$("#color_change").addClass("myClass");
}
else{
$("#color_change").addClass("myotherClass");
}
})
</script>   no class adding in button where i commiting mistake check website please http://onlinegiftstore.in/ i have added a id on cart help please